# Can't render data from redux state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am building simple forum app and I want to render information about replies to the forum post. Here is some redux code i use to do that: Action function and reducer:

```
export const getRoomContext = (id) => async (dispatch) =>{
try{
    dispatch({type: 'GET_ROOM_MESSAGES1_REQUEST'})
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://localhost:5001/api/Forum/posts/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: GET_ROOM_MESSAGES_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    })
}
catch(error){
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ROOM_MESSAGES_FAIL,
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail ? error.response.data.detail : error.message
    })
}}

export const getRoomContextReducer = (state = {}, action) =>{
switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_ROOM_MESSAGES1_REQUEST':
        return {loading: true, getRoominfo: []}
    
    case GET_ROOM_MESSAGES_SUCCESS:
        return {loading: false, getRoominfo: action.payload}

    case GET_ROOM_MESSAGES_FAIL:
        return {loading: false, error: action.payload}

    default:
        return state
}}
```

Here is the code i use to render data on screen:

```
export default function PostScreen2() {

const {id} = useParams()
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const downMessage = useSelector(state => state.downMessage)
const {error, loading, getRoominfo} = downMessage



useEffect(() =>{
    dispatch(getRoomContext(id))
}, [dispatch, id])

return(
   <div>{getRoominfo.id}</div>
)
```

And the problem is that everytime I try to render {getRoominfo.id} my states dissapear in my redux google extension and I have whole blank page with error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'). But when i try to render asd It renders fine, the states are showing up and there is no errors. And then when I once again write {getRoominfo.id} it actually renders on my screen but after i refresh the page there are same errors.

Comment: It is because initially the `getRoominfo` variable is undefined and you are trying to access id of undefined. What you can do is additionally check whether it is not undefined `{getRoominfo && getRoominfo.id}`. or if it is fetching some data show a loader `{loading ? <p>Loading</p> : <div>{getRoominfo.id</div>}`.

Comment: @Tirth Trivedi Yes, that is exactly what I had to do, thank you very much.